# Binding multiple arguments to member functions in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, bind

Say I have class `A` with member function `int f() { return m_; }` where `m_` is a data member.  I have a `vector<A>` called `vec`, and I want to find the object with maximum `m_` value in `vec` using `std::max_element`.  I can do it with a lambda:

```
auto cmp = [] (A& x, A& y) { return x.f() < y.f(); };
A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
```

Is there some `bind` (or some such) trickery that will allow me to do it without a lambda and without defining my own comparator from scratch?  Please don't suggest better ways to solve the max finding problem.  It's only an example.  The general question is how to wrap a function object that takes more than one argument (e.g., `std::less<int>`, which I would use as the comparator in the above example) in such a way that that arguments sent to it go through some other function (or member function) before getting to it.

Comment: Since you're arbitrarily selective on your decision of which `f()` shall be your comparator base, I see little hope of doing this *without* a custom comparator of *some* kind (be it functor or lambda, and my money is on the former for pointer-to-member convenience). Or... I didn't understand the problem at all (its 2:30am here, really should be in bed right now).

Comment: Look into [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), [`std::placeholders::_1`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) and related.

Comment: When I said "without defining my own comparator from scratch" I meant that I want to put something together from things like `less<>` and other building blocks (such as `bind`), that would ultimately call `f()`.  I already looked into `bind` and `placeholders` but couldn't figure out how to do it with those.

Comment: @WhozCraig: There's a well-known alternative which doesn't need a custom comparator: a transform iterator which returns `wrappedIter->f()` from its `operator*`.

Comment: I hope you realize that using `bind` will be slower.

Comment: @MSalters, that doesn't count in my book. I don't want to define new classes or functions.

Comment: @Ari: Shouldn't be necessary, Boost already has one IIRC. It's really no different from `bind`, except that it's simpler (Only need to apply `->f()` once)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
A& max = *std::max_element(begin(vec), end(vec)
    , std::bind(
        &std::less<int>::operator()
        , std::less<int>()
        , std::bind(&A::f, _1)
        , std::bind(&A::f, _2)
    )
);
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/4Ame8t)

However, if I ever saw this in code review, I'd immediately say "turn that ugliness into a lambda."

---

Thanks to @n.m. for poining out that the code can be shortened a bit:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
A& max = *std::max_element(begin(vec), end(vec)
    , std::bind(
        std::less<int>()
        , std::bind(&A::f, _1)
        , std::bind(&A::f, _2)
    )
);
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/72z5bZ)

I still consider a lambda more readable, though. Bear in mind that you can use a lambda directly in the call to `max_element()` (no need for the variable `cmp` in your original code).

Comment: Ok. that's just awesome.

Comment: `operator()` is called `operator()` for a reason: you don't have to name it when you want to call it ;) `std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::bind(&A::f, _1), std::bind(&A::f, _2))` is enough.

Comment: Interesting.  This was exactly my first thought, but I was so sure the `_1` and `_2` wouldn't pass through (not knowing how all of this is implemented), that I didn't even try it.  Lemme see if it works.

Comment: Yup. It works.  So now I'll dig into placeholders to understand how this magic happens.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ari The outermost functor is a `std::bind`, which knows how to interpret placeholders and nested bind expressions. That's all that is needed for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways you can supply a predicate to a algorithm. Below you'll see a number of examples of how this can be done. Here's a summary of the calls to `std::max_element()`:

```
//here we're using an in-place lambda
A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](A& x, A&y){ return x.f() < y.f(); });
// here we're binding to a non-static member function
A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(&A::compare, A(0), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
// here we're binding to a non-member function
A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(gcompare, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
// here we're using the non-member function without using bind
A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), gcompare);
```

We could also use `std::function`.

Here's the full test source code so that you can play with it yourself:

```
class A
{
    int m_ = 0;
public:
    A(int max) : m_(max)
    {

    }
    A(const A& that)
    {
        m_ = that.m_;
    }
    A& operator=(const A& that)
    {
        m_ = that.m_;
    }
    int f() const
    {
        return m_;
    }
    bool compare(const A&x, const A&y) const
    {
        return x.m_ < y.m_;
    }
    static bool scompare(const A&x, const A&y)
    {
        return x.m_ < y.m_;
    }
};

static bool gcompare(const A&x, const A&y)
{
    return x.f() < y.f();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(5);
    vec.emplace_back(7);
    vec.emplace_back(4);
    vec.emplace_back(9);
    vec.emplace_back(12);
    vec.emplace_back(1);


    A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](A& x, A&y){ return x.f() < y.f(); });
    A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(&A::compare, A(0), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(gcompare, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    A& max_elem = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), gcompare);

}
```